# Problems passing off parameters to display multiple embedded OpenSourceMap in separate FancyBox overlays in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, parameters, embed, openstreetmap

I'm working on a project in Wordpress that requires me to tag photo posts on an overlay map. I'm using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin in Wordpress to pass off latitude, longitude, and location name fields and inserting them into a link that says the Location name and links to a FancyBox overlay that displays the embedded version of OpenStreetMap with lat/lon coordinates passed off as variables in the link URL. My code looks something like this:

```
This picture was taken at <a class="fancybox-iframe"        
href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?
bbox=-77.44244992733002%2C37.536657186828165%2C-
77.43791699409485%2C37.53942209826503&amp;layer=mapnik&amp;marker=<?php the_field('lat'); ?
>%2C<?php the_field('lon'); ?>"><?php the_field('location_name'); ?></a>
```

The problem lies in the "bbox" parameter. It look as if it pulled this from the original embed code I pulled from OSM. If I remove it, it zooms all the way out on the map, displaying the entire world. I need it to use the marker as a center and set the "bbox" variable and zoom accordingly.

I've found a few other solutions on here, but they only work for a one-off approach, as you have to manually enter the coordinates within the script. I'm going to be listing a bunch of these on the front page of the site, so that approach won't work.

Any help solving this problem or finding an alternative would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: whats wrong with bbox ? whats desired value of bbox ?

Comment: Right now, the problem is that it's static based on the location I first searched from to get the embed code. If I pass lat/lon parameters for the marker that are outside of that bounding box, they don't get displayed right off the bat (without zooming out, of course). The desired value of bbox would depend on where ever the marker is.

In Google Maps, you could pass the lat/long and zoom values and it would display accordingly, using the lat/long as the center. Not so with OSM, as it has to have a bbox value. That sort of Google Maps embed functionality is what I'm looking for.

Comment: The regular [openstreetmap.org](http://www.openstreetmap.org) website works the same way (just lat, lon and zoom). There are various other ways to embed a OSM map, for example by using [Leaflet](http://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/getting-started-with-leaflet/) or [OpenLayers](http://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/getting-started-with-openlayers/). They offer more advanced features. The current OSM website for example uses Leaflet. But it shouldn't be a problem to calculate the bbox from the given lat and lon values and a fixed zoom level.